# repeater inside an update panel - ItemComand Codes Peroblem - Calling A javascript function With ScriptManager In Code Behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager

my repeater in aspx area is like below :
`this repeater is inside a master page - pages are base on master and content pages`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="imgArrowIconInsideRepeater" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Login/ArrowIcon.png"
                />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFilePath" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FilePath")%>' />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFileName" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FileName")%>' />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFileSize" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FileSize")%>' />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFileCreationDate" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FileCreationDate")%>' />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbFile" runat="server" CommandName="lbFile_Click" CssClass="lbFileInRepeater"
                ><%# Eval("FileName")%></asp:LinkButton>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblFileCreationDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileCreationDate", "{0:yyyy/MM/dd - tt h:m:s}") %>'
                CssClass="lblFileCreationDateInRepeater" ></asp:Label>
            |
            <asp:Label ID="lblFileSize" runat="server" Text='<%# GetFileSize(Eval("FileSize"))%>'
                CssClass="lblFileSizeInRepeater"></asp:Label>
            <div class="EmptyDiv">
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

also i have a scriptmanager in my master page like below :

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

my c# codes in code behind is like below :

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        //The Below Line Does Not Work - Always Is Null
        //NewAddedFiles currentItem = (NewAddedFiles)e.Item.DataItem;

        HiddenField hfFilePath = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfFilePath");
        HiddenField hfFileName = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfFileName");
        HiddenField hfFileSize = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfFileSize");
        HiddenField hfFileCreationDate = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfFileCreationDate");

        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "lbFile_Click":
                {
                    if (Session["User_ID"] != null)
                    {
                        DataSet dsDownload = DataLayer.Download.Size_By_UserID_Today(int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["User_ID"].ToString()), DateTime.Now);
                        if (dsDownload.Tables["Download"].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            DataRow drDownload = dsDownload.Tables["Download"].Rows[0];

                            int SumOfFileSize4Today = int.Parse(drDownload["FileSizSum"].ToString());

                            if (SumOfFileSize4Today + int.Parse(hfFileSize.Value) <= 1073741824)//1 GB = 1024*1024*1024 bytes = 1073741824 bytes
                            //if (SumOfFileSize4Today + int.Parse(hfFileSize.Value) <= 100000)
                            {
                                DataLayer.Download.InsertRow(
                                           int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["User_ID"].ToString()),
                                           DateTime.Now,
                                           hfFilePath.Value,
                                           hfFileName.Value,
                                           hfFileSize.Value,
                                           DateTime.Parse(hfFileCreationDate.Value)
                                         );
                                Response.Redirect("~/HandlerForRepeater.ashx?path=" + hfFilePath.Value);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "YouCanNotDownloadAnyMore_SizeOverload", "YouCanNotDownloadAnyMore_SizeOverload();", true);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (int.Parse(hfFileSize.Value) <= 1073741824)
                            //if (int.Parse(hfFileSize.Value) <= 100000)
                            {
                                DataLayer.Download.InsertRow(
                                           int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["User_ID"].ToString()),
                                           DateTime.Now,
                                           hfFilePath.Value,
                                           hfFileName.Value,
                                           hfFileSize.Value,
                                           DateTime.Parse(hfFileCreationDate.Value)
                                         );
                                Response.Redirect("~/HandlerForRepeater.ashx?path=" + hfFilePath.Value);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "YouCanNotDownloadAnyMore_SizeOverload", "YouCanNotDownloadAnyMore_SizeOverload();", true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "plzLoginFirst_ForDownload", "plzLoginFirst_ForDownload();", true);
                    }
                    break;
                }

            default:
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is about these lines : `start with  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`
why these lines do n't work inside update panel? - without update panel every thing is ok.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved by this change :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), 
    "plzLoginFirst_ForDownload", "plzLoginFirst_ForDownload();", true);
```

Comment: a master page inherits from `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`, whereas a normal page inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`. The `Page` property of a master page gives you the actual current page. I guess a `Page` object is needed by the `RegisterStartupScript` method.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` tries to run something on "startup", ie. when the page has loaded or similar. With an `UpdatePanel`, the server is just sending back a blob of HTML to the client, which is inserted into the already-loaded page.

Without an `UpdatePanel`, you're sending back a whole new page, which will be loaded by the browser in the normal way, going through the whole page loading process.

So maybe you'll need to already have the script in the page, and handle the client-side events for the update panel refreshing. Can't remember how to do this off the top of my head unfortunately - maybe something like this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397499.aspx

Comment: thanks for answer / but what is the solution ?

Comment: @MoonLight: well, you asked why the code didn't work inside an UpdatePanel! If you check out that MSDN link, it has some example javascript showing how to handle the event. Try using this in your page, you should then be able to insert the code you had in the script you were trying to register.

Comment: but in my previous projects(without master page) the upper codes in my q work perfect - i do n't know this problem is in relationship with master and content page or not! however thanks for attention and edit...